In a democracy, what are the philosophical justifications for protection of minorities?
Democracy is characterised as rule by the people or rule by the majority. However, it has long been recognised that the majority cannot, without good reason, infringe the rights of minorities. Free speech, an important element of democracy, might infringe the rights of minorities by inciting hatred. Some jurisdictions already outlaw hate speech. Free speech has previously been abridged on the grounds of defamation, endangering national security, infringing intellectual property etc. So are democracies justified in not tolerating intolerance?

See Paradox of tolerance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance

Every person probably falls in to at least one of the many overlapping minorities that exist. It's just self-interest to protect minorities.

@ScottRowe would be a good answer

I don't know how to make it into a longer answer though. Also, the 'tolerance' part is only in the last sentence, so I don't know if it is an afterthought, or the entire question? The title question has nothing to do with tolerance, as I understand it.

I just want to point out that this question is taking an extremely weak example. You want to start with "should majorities be able to vote that the minority be fed to piranhas" and work from there. Whether one has a right to have the government use the threat of violence to compel people not to tell other people to hate you or not, it's the sort of thing that one only thinks about if one lives in a community where one's real concerns are secure.

I suggest you listen to Kaia @ScottRowe [Or just the comment upvotes]. BTW I am in the miniscule minority of people who have 3719 white hairs on their heads

It seems like people are happy with my comment.

“[A]re democracies justified in not tolerating intolerance?”, that’s the final question of your post.
The principle of tolerance is not specific for democracies. It is a basic principle for living together in any social group. Tolerance means:

The freedom of the individual ends where the freedom of others begins.

The idea, but not the explicit formulation above, is due also to Kant.

@andrós Tolerance means to establish a balance between different interests in a social group. Tolerance is not to discover but to establish.
